# Can I intercept a form action?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have to submit a form to an external payment system

```
<form action="https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

Everything works correctly with hidden inputs, but I need to generate the order number `onclick` the PAY button and send it with that POST that executes the action.

I have tried to execute a function in the action, but I cannot do the post after opening another window.

the server is not good for me either, because I have to launch the post from the front.

do I have an option to intercept this form?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onsubmit` handler where you modify the form data - if you don't `event.preventDefault()` in that handler, the form will continue posting as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try doing is override the default form behavior and inject the data you need, then submit the form.

Here's how one might achieve that:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('my-form');

let input = document.getElementById('foo');

function handleSubmit(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  let formData = new FormData();
  // then appen all your data
  
  console.log(input.value);
  
  formData.append("foo", input.value);
  // append all your other data
  
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(form.method, form.action);
  request.send(formData);
  
  // after the send, you can do whatever you like, including redirecting, refreshing, etc.
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago" id="my-form">
   <input value="bar" type="hidden" id="foo" />
   
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```